# Mystery of the mysterious P

Tags: c, malloc, realloc, cs50

**Background:**

I'm trying to create a program that takes a user name(assuming that input is clean), and prints out the initials of the name.

Objective:

- Trying my hand out at C programming with CS50
- Getting myself familiar with malloc & realloc

Code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

string prompt(void);
char *getInitials(string input);
char *appendArray(char *output,char c,int count);

//Tracks # of initials
int counter = 0;

int main(void){

    string input = prompt();
    char *output = getInitials(input);
    for(int i = 0; i < counter ; i++){

        printf("%c",toupper(output[i]));
    }


}

string prompt(void){

    string input;

    do{
        printf("Please enter your name: ");
        input = get_string();
    }while(input == NULL);

    return input;

}

char *getInitials(string input){

    bool initials = true;
    char *output;
    output = malloc(sizeof(char) * counter);
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n ; i++){
        //32 -> ASCII code for spacebar
        //9  -> ASCII code for tab
        if(input[i] == 32 || input[i] == 9 ){
            //Next char after spaces/tab will be initial
            initials = true;


        }else{//Not space/tab
            if(initials == true){
                counter++;
                output = appendArray(output,input[i],counter);

                initials = false;


            }        

        }
        // eprintf("Input[i] is : %c\n",input[i]);
        // eprintf("Counter is : %i\n",counter);
        // eprintf("i is : %i\n",i);
        // eprintf("n is : %i\n",n);



    }

    return output;
}

char *appendArray(char *output,char c,int count){

    // allocate an array of some initial (fairly small) size;
    // read into this array, keeping track of how many elements you've read;
    // once the array is full, reallocate it, doubling the size and preserving (i.e. copying) the contents;
    // repeat until done.


    //pointer to memory
    char *data = malloc(0);
    //Increase array size by 1
    data = realloc(output,sizeof(char) * count);
    //append the latest initial
    strcat(data,&c);
    printf("Value of c is :%c\n",c);
    printf("Value of &c is :%s\n",&c);
    for(int i = 0; i< count ; i++){
        printf("Output: %c\n",data[i]);
    }
    return data;

}
```

Problem:

The output is not what i expected as there is a mysterious P appearing in the output.

E.g When i enter the name Barack Obama, instead of getting the result:BO, i get the result BP and the same happens for whatever name i choose to enter, with the last initial always being P.

Output:

```
Please enter your name: Barack Obama
Value of c is :B
Value of &c is :BP
Output: B
Value of c is :O
Value of &c is :OP
Output: B
Output: P
BP
```

What i've done:

I've traced the problem to the appendArray function, and more specifically to the value of &c (Address of c) though i have no idea what's causing the P to appear,what it means, why it appears and how i can get rid of it.

The value of P shows up no matter when i input.

Insights as to why it's happening and what i can do to solve it will be much appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: There's a [cs50 stack exchange site](http://cs50.stackexchange.com/) in case you're interested.

Comment: @pmg I didn't know that. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: `output = malloc(sizeof(char) * counter);` --> `output = malloc(++counter);
    *output = 0;`

Comment: `strcat(data,&c);
    printf("Value of c is :%c\n",c);
    printf("Value of &c is :%s\n",&c);` --> `strncat(data, &c, 1);`

Comment: `for(int i = 0; i < counter ; i++){` --> `for(int i = 0; output[i] ; i++){`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several issues, in decreasing order of importance...

First issue - `c` in `appendArray` is *not a string* - it is not a *sequence* of character values terminated by a 0. `c` is a single `char` object, storing a single `char` value.

When you try to print `c` *as a string*, as in

```
printf("Value of &c is :%s\n",&c);
```

`printf` writes out the *sequence* of character values starting at the address of `c` until it sees a 0-valued byte.  *For whatever reason*, the byte immediately following `c` contains the value 80, which is the ASCII (or UTF-8) code for the character `'P'`.  The next byte contains a 0 (or there's a sequence of bytes containing non-printable characters, followed by a 0-valued byte).

Similarly, using `&c` as the argument to `strcat` is inappropriate, since `c` *is not a string*.  Instead, you should do something like

```
data[count-1] = c;
```

Secondly, if you want to treat the `data` array as a string, you must make sure to size it at least 1 more than the number of initials and write a 0 to the final element:

```
data[count-1] = 0; // after all initials have been stored to data
```

Third,

```
char *data = malloc(0);
```

serves no purpose, the behavior is implementation-defined, and you *immediately* overwrite the result of `malloc(0)` with a call to `realloc`:

```
data = realloc(output,sizeof(char) * count);
```

So, get rid of the `malloc(0)` call altogether; either just initialize `data` to `NULL`, or initialize it with the `realloc` call:

```
char *data = realloc( output, sizeof(char) * count );
```

Fourth, avoid using "magic numbers" - numeric constants with meaning beyond their immediate, literal value.  When you want to compare against *character* values, use *character* constants.  IOW, change

```
if(input[i] == 32 || input[i] == 9 ){
```

to

```
if ( input[i] == ' ' || input[i] == '\t' )
```

That way you don't have to worry about whether the character encoding is ASCII, UTF-8, EBCDIC, or some other system.  `' '` means *space* everywhere, `'\t'` means *tab* everywhere.

Finally...

I know part of your motivation for this exercise is to get familiar with `malloc` and `realloc`, but I want to caution you about some things:

`realloc` is potentially an expensive operation, it *may* move data to a new location, and it *may* fail.  You really don't want to `realloc` a buffer a byte at a time.  Instead, it's better to `realloc` in chunks.  A typical strategy is to multiply the current buffer size by some factor > 1 (typically doubling):

```
char *tmp = realloc( data, current_size * 2 );
if ( tmp )
{
  current_size *= 2;
  data = tmp;
}
```

You should *always* check the result of a `malloc`, `calloc`, or `realloc` call to make sure it succeeded before attempting to access that memory.

Minor stylistic notes:

Avoid global variables where you can.  There's no reason `counter` should be global, especially since you pass it as an argument to `appendArray`.  Declare it local to `main` and pass it as an argument (by reference) to `getInput`:

```
int main( void )
{
  int counter = 0;
  ...
  char *output = getInitials( input, &counter );
  for(int i = 0; i < counter ; i++)
  {
    printf("%c",toupper(output[i]));
  } 
  ...
}

/**
 * The "string" typedef is an abomination that *will* lead you astray,
 * and I want to have words with whoever created the CS50 header.
 *
 * They're trying to abstract away the concept of a "string" in C, but 
 * they've done it in such a way that the abstraction is "leaky" - 
 * in order to use and access the input object correctly, you *need to know*
 * the representation behind the typedef, which in this case is `char *`.
 *
 * Secondly, not every `char *` object points to the beginning of a 
 * *string*.    
 *
 * Hiding pointer types behind typedefs is almost always bad juju.  
 */
char *getInitials( const char *input, int *counter ) 
{
   ...
   (*counter)++;                                   // parens are necessary here
   output = appendArray(output,input[i],*counter); // need leading * here
   ...
}
```

Comment: Well deserving of the word *"education"*.